# My spouse and kid disappeared after the battle for Windhelm

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So, I am married to Revyn Sadri and I adopted Sofi as my kid and we all lived happily in my house in Riften. However, after I complete the reunification of Skyrim and killed Ulfric...They're gone. My other adopted kid is still there, but Revyn and Sofi have vanished. They're both from Windhelm, so I went back there, but no joy. Couldn't find them. Help? Please? Also note, I'm on a PS3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you should do but are you sure they weren't killed? How much time passed(game time) before you realized they were missing? After a certain period of time (again game time) the game "cleans" or removes the dead, also check the hall of the dead, bc if they have died they're remains or belongings could be in a coffin (I used to play PS3 skyrim 4-5yrs ago &just recently  got the 1 for PS4 so I would most definitely get a second opinion)just putting my 2 cents out there

Comment: Children cannot be killed so Sofi will certainly not be dead.

Answer (score 2):

### Known (though unconfirmed) Bug

Though I'm unable to find any information regarding the disappearance of Revyn himself, there is indeed some information on Sofie. [A bug is known](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Sofie#Bugs) that Sofia will disappear once Battle for Windhelm is completed, though the cause is unknown.

A possible fix (according to the Wiki) is to ask another household member to move to another property - this may get Sofia to move there too.

### Possible Cause & Solution (Speculative)

I think the most likely cause is the fact that both characters are part of the `TownWindhelmFaction` - this "faction" (faction is a technical term here, not synonymous with "organiation") contains everyone who lives in Windhelm. During the Battle for Windhelm the game will send every member of this faction inside buildings to keep them safe.

Now, when you asked Revyn and Sofie to move into your home they should have been removed from these factions - I'm guessing the bug occurred at this time and they *weren't* removed, which meant the quest would have sent them indoors, and the location chosen was probably related to the characters' other factions; Sofie has the faction `WindhelmCandlehearthHallFaction` and so probably went to Candlehearth Hall (check for her there) and Revyn also had the factions `WindhelmCornerclubPatrons` and `WindhelmPawnshopOwnerFaction` so be sure to check the New Gnisis Cornerclub and Sadri's Used Wares for him.

*As a disclaimer, those last two paragraphs are speculation on my part based on my knowledge of the game and how it works. I have not reproduced this issue myself so am unable to test this as a solution.*